# JAXB / XSD implement Java generic

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I have defined a complex type in XSD schema, which is let's say: parent and has attribute with type anyType.

In a child type I want to define the exact type which will be used for that attribute or override get method which will specify which object is returned.

I want to have Parent.java class like this:

```
class Parent {
  Object attr;
  Object getAttr() {..}
}

class Child extends Parent {
  @Override
  ChildAttr getAttr() {..}
}
```

The question is - how to define this in XSD or JAXB bindings?